# react-data-table-components error warning: react does not recognize the `sortActive`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, react-data-table-component

I am using react-data-table-components and just following the instruction given by the documentation, but it's showing me an error (some of it is in text below):

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlfD4.png)

Below is the sample code I copied in the documentation:

```
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

const App = () => {

  const columns = [
      {
          name: 'Title',
          selector: row => row.title,
      },
      {
          name: 'Year',
          selector: row => row.year,
      },
  ];
  const data = [
      {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Beetlejuice',
          year: '1988',
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Ghostbusters',
          year: '1984',
      },
  ]

  return (
    <>
        <DataTable
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
        />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Below is the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file:

*[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0whm.png)*

These are the errors showing in my console:

> StyledComponent.ts:159 styled-components: it looks like an unknown prop "responsive" is being sent through to the DOM, which will likely trigger a React console error. If you would like automatic filtering of unknown props, you can opt-into that behavior via `<StyleSheetManager shouldForwardProp={...}>` (connect an API like `@emotion/is-prop-valid`) or consider using transient props (`$` prefix for automatic filtering.)
>
> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: React does not recognize the `sortActive` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `sortactive` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
>
> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `dense`.
>
> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: React does not recognize the `fixedHeader` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `fixedheader` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: put error on words

Comment: I just did sir, that is all the error i was getting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code is correct. What happens is that ``react-data-table-component`` is using an old version of ``styled-components``. So, to remove the errors downgrade ``styled-components`` to v5.3.3. Also, there's a PR on ``react-data-table-component`` repository for this problem, but it hasn't been merged yet.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed the issue by downgrading my version of `styled-components` to v5.3.3, [as @aldwinp35 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76887518/react-data-table-components-error-warning-react-does-not-recognize-the-sortact/77052733#comment135630930_76887518):

> The code is correct. What happens is that `react-data-table-component` is using an old version of `styled-components`. So, to remove the errors downgrade `styled-components` to v5.3.3. Also, there's a PR on `react-data-table-component` repository for this problem, but it hasn't been merged yet.

Answer (score 1):

Byron Escobar is absolutely correct. Downgrading `styled-components` solves the problem. However, I'd like to point out that downgrading to version 5.3.11
(which is the latest release of version 5) instead of 5.3.3, also solves the problem. At least it did in my case. In my case, the error was:
 `` Warning: React does not recognize the `fixedHeader` prop on a DOM element ``

If you take a look at https://styled-components.com/releases you'll see that release 6 of `styled-components` has **breaking changes**. That's possibly why when you use `react-data-table-component` with `styled-components` version 6, errors are showing in your console.

Also note that if you install `react-data-table-component`, without explicitly
specifying the version of `styled-components`, then by default, `react-data-table-component` pulls in `styled-components` version 6. This can be verified by viewing the `package.json` file.

So, to downgrade `styled-components`, I had to:
`npm uninstall react-data-table-component styled-components`

and then
`npm install react-data-table-component styled-components@5`

That fixed the issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with styled-components like this:

> StyledComponent.ts:142 styled-components: it looks like an unknown prop "logo" is being sent through to the DOM, which will likely trigger a React console error. If you would like automatic filtering of unknown props, you can opt-into that behavior via `<StyleSheetManager shouldForwardProp={...}>` (connect an API like `@emotion/is-prop-valid`) or consider using transient props (`$` prefix for automatic filtering.)

If you send a prop into styled div from styled-components, you must send prop to styled-component back with '$'. For instance: <StyledSection $logo='true'/>